# How to design the relations between USER and FAVORITE(or LIKE) models in DB

Tags: database-design, data-modeling

I have these models(tables): `USER`, `PHOTO`, `BOOK`, `QUESTION` etc.
And now I wanna add the `favorite` or `like` feature to the site, that is user can 'like' some photos or books or questions, and of course a photo can be liked by many users.
So I wanna ask you how to implement this kind of thing.

a page to show the books, photos, quesitons etc which are liked by the current login user;
how many people like the book.

Here is my thoughts, give it simple.

**A**

table: `books_users`

book_id  user_id

table: `photos_users`

photo_id  user_id

table: `questions_users`

question_id  user_id

**B**

table: `users_likes`

`object_id  user_id  type`

column 'type ' is set to hold the 'book', 'photo' infos.

A or B?

What really bothers me is in OOP we're trying to create a inheritence relationship between the objects that hold the same. But in relational databse, is that good to keep the things in one table(plan B), or keep them seperate(plan A).I don't have too much experiences in DB design so would you please tell the me pros and cons?

Comment: Do you want each user to be able to like multiple items, or just one?

Comment: That would be multiple items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: like_model_01]

This uses supertype/subtype relationship. For a few more similar examples and explanations **[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:196713+subtype)** and how to **[create tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295879/best-mysql-table-structure-2-parents-1-child/3299061#3299061)**.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the diagram! Very impressive! It also reminded me that the relationships between category/tag and posts in Wordpress are almost the same way. I'll check out the links.