# Properly modelling a mutually exclusive one to many relation

Tags: sql, database-design, data-modeling

I have entities `Workflows`, `Steps` and `Fields`. They relate to each other like this:

- A `Workflow` has many `Steps` and `Fields`.
- A `Step` has many `Fields`.

A `Field` can belong to either a `Workflow` or a `Step` but not to both at once. My first option is to add two foreign key columns to `Field` where one will always be `null`. So the fields table will have the following columns:

```
Fields
- id
- name
- step_id (FK to steps)
- workflow_id (FK to workflows)
```

This allows to enforce uniqueness of the name in the scope of the parent (by creating a unique index on the parent ID and the name) as well as use foreign key cascading deletes ensuring any time a `Workflow` or `Step` is deleted the related `Fields` will be deleted as well. However, one column is always `null` and if I introduce another parent of `Field` in the future it would require adding yet another FK column.

In an attempt to normalize this, I can set up join tables and express the relationship in another way:

```
Fields
- id
- name

WorkflowFields
- workflow_id (FK to workflows)
- field_id (FK to fields)

StepFields
- step_id (FK to steps)
- field_id (FK to fields)
```

Now I don't have any null values but I lose the ability to enforce uniqueness and cascade the deletes (when a `Workflow` or `Step` is deleted, the join record `WorkflowField` or `StepField` will be deleted but not the actual `Field` record itself).

- How do I handle the uniqueness requirement? Should `name` be a column on the join table instead of the `fields` table? This feels wrong but I don't see another way.
- How do I handle cascading deletes? I want the corresponding `Field` to be deleted any time the `Workflow` or `Step` or any of the join models are deleted. Are database triggers my only option here?
- Is there a better alternative or are these the options I'm limited to?

Comment: What is a field?  If it's what I think it is (a descriptor), then it makes more sense to include descriptor elements in the Workflow and Step entities.  Entity names should be singular.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc - a field is another entity that has a name, a value and a few other columns. Both Steps and Workflows can have multiple fields. (This is in the context of a Rails app where class names are singular but table names are plural.)

Comment: Okay.  Have separate field entities, one for the workflow and one for the step.  This eliminates the need for a null foreign key.  The application code can handle name uniqueness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way of stating the problem is *a step may be used exactly once*, ergo:

Add columns to field to record where it's used.

```
create table field (
  id int not null primary key,
  -- other columns
  workflow_id int references workflow,
  step_id int references step,
  constraint overuse check (workflow_id is null or step_id is null)
)
```

The constraint ensures the field is used in either a workflow or a step, but not both.

Both FK's being null is OK - it just means the field is defined but not currently used.

It's fine to add more parents in the future by adding more FK columns - that is reflecting reality.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [MySQL: Two n:1 relations, but not both at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145084/mysql-two-n1-relations-but-not-both-at-once/3145711#3145711).

Basically, it proposes to introduce a table containing a collection of fields (1 to many). WorkFlow and Steps will have as foreign-key the primary-key of this field-collection-table (one-to-one). Every time a Workflow (or a Step) is created, a new FieldCollection-entry is created (the creation always happens together, FieldCollection can be compared with a parent-class in OO-Programming). .

```
FieldCollection
 - fieldCollection_id

Field
 - field_id
 - fieldCollection_id

Workflow
 - workflow_id
 - fieldCollection_id

Steps
 - steps_id
 - fieldCollection_id
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! That's a interesting alternative but unfortunately don't address the cascading deletes. I would still need to manually handle deletion of the `FieldCollection`.