# multiple tables need one to many relationship

Tags: sql, database-design

I have a SQL database with multiple tables: A, B, C, D. Entities in those tables are quite different things, with different columns, and different kind of relations between them.
However, they all share one little thing: the need for a comment system which, in this case, would have an identical structure: author_id, date, content, etc.

I wonder which strategy would be the best for this schema to have A,..D tables use a comment system. In a classical 'blog' web site I would use a one-to-many relationship with a post_id inside the 'comments' table.

Here it looks like I need an A_comments, B_comments, etc tables to handle this problem, which looks a little bit weird.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Side note: Tables don't have relations, they *are* relations (or at least, they would be if SQL properly implemented the relational model). What they have between them is *relationships*.

Comment: @Marcelo, interesting point, could you expand it a bit? (although I'm fine with english, it is not my mother tongue). How are tables themselves already relations?

Comment: It isn't really an *English* thing so much as a question of database terminology. The *relation* is a very specific concept in the relational model (informally, a set of tuples with a header); its counterpart in SQL is the table. When you refer to "relations" between tables, what you really mean is *foreign keys*, which are a special case of constraints between tables, and which may be casually referred to as *relationships*. But you should avoid using the term "relation" so as to prevent confusion with the formal meaning of the word.

Comment: The word *relation* comes from mathematics.  It's a set of ordered tuples.  The relational model  of data was derived from the mathematics of relations.  Using the word relationships for the association between tables helps with clarity.  This may work out very differently in other languages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Create a `comment` table with a `comment_id` primary key and the various attributes of a comment.

Additionally, create `A_comment` thus:

```
CREATE TABLE A_comment (
    comment_id PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES comment(comment_id),
    A_id REFERENCES A(A_id)
)
```

Do likewise for B, C and D. This ensures referential integrity between `comment` and all the other tables, which you can't do if you store the ids to A, B, C and D directly in `comment`.

Declaring `A_comment.comment_id` as the primary key ensures that a comment can only belong to one entry in A. It doesn't prevent a comment from belonging to an entry in A and an entry in B, but there's only so much you can achieve with foreign keys; this would require database-level constraints, which no database I know of supports.

This design also doesn't prevent orphaned comments, but I can't think of any way to prevent this in SQL, except, of course, to do the very thing you wanted to avoid: create multiple comment tables.

Comment: Doesn't it make more sense from a data modeling perspective to duplicate the columns between `A_comment`, `B_comment`, etc.? The reason is, any given comment ID will be referenced exactly once in a `comment_id` column. I feel like having a FK that's referenced only once doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Utku I'm not sure what you mean. What would [A-D]_comment look like under your suggestion?

Comment: Like `CREATE TABLE A_comment (title TEXT, body TEXT, author INT, A_id INT)`. That is, there won't be no `comment` table and instead, the columns that would be in the `comment` table would be duplicated among `[A-D]_comment` tables. I thought with your approach, since any given PK in `comment` would be referenced by another table exactly once, there is no point of having that extra table.

Comment: @Utku That approach has its pros and cons, but it's exactly the approach the OP wanted to avoid. I was offering an alternative solution.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar "problem" with comments for more different object types (e.g. articles and shops in my case, each type has it's own table).

What I did: in my comments table I have two columns that manage the linking:

- `object_type` ([ENUM type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html)) that determines the object/table we are linking to, and
- `object_id` (unsigned integer type that matches the primary key of your other tables (or the biggest of them)) that point to the exact row in the particular table.

The column structure is then: `id`, `object_type`, `object_id`, `author_id`, `date`, `content`, etc.

Important thing here is to have an index on both of the columns, `(object_type, object_id)`, to make indexing fast.

Comment: Nice, I search semilar solution, But i want to keep my database normalization, Any Idea how to manage the relationsheps between thouse tables?

Answer (score 4):

I presume that you are talking of a single comments table with a foreign key to "exactly one of" A, B, C or D.

The fact that SQL cannot handle this is one of its fundamental weaknesses.  The question gets asked over and over and over again.

See, e.g.

[What is the best way to enforce a 'subset' relationship with integrity constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522320/what-is-the-best-way-to-enforce-a-subset-relationship-with-integrity-constraint)

Your constraint is a "foreign key" from your "single comments" table into a view, which is the union of the identifiers in A, B, C and D.  SQL supports only foreign keys into base tables.

Observe that SQL as a language does have support for your situation, in the form of CREATE ASSERTION.  I know of no SQL products that support that statement, however.

EDIT
You should also keep in mind that with a 'single' comments table, you might need to enforce disjointness between the keys in A,B,C and D, for otherwise it might happen some time that a comment automatically gets "shared" between entity occurrences from different tables, which might not be desirable.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a single comments table and within that table have a column that contains a value differentiating which table the comment belongs to - ie a 1 in that column means it's a comment for table A, 2 for table B, and so on.  If you didn't want to have "magic numbers" in the comments table, you could have another table that has just two columns: one with the number and another detailing which table the number represents.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a separate comment table for every other, one is enough. Every comment will have a unique ID, so you don't have to worry about conflicts.