# Multiple tables with one to many relationship(Laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have 3 tables namely A, B and C.
All 3 of them need to make use of a notes table(i.e. A has many notes and a note belongs to A. The same follows for remaining 2 tables).
So I created 3 more tables: A_note, B_note and C_note(as mentioned here: [multiple tables need one to many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537779/multiple-tables-need-one-to-many-relationship)).

Is there a way to do CRUD operations on these tables(A_note, B_note and C_note)  similar to the way we handle pivot table in many-to-many relationship?

Please suggest a way forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `polymorphic` relationships for this. It allows multiple models to make use of a single table.

[Have a look at the documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations)

In your particular case, each of your tables would reference a `noteable_id` column and a `noteable_type`.

The `noteable_id` will contain the id of the `(A/B/C)` model.

The `noteable_type` will contain the string name of the model `(A/B/C)`.

The `(A/B/C)` models will now get a new attribute:

```
/**
 * (A/B/C) Model(s)
 */
public function notes()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Notes', 'noteable');
}
```

And the `note` model will initiate it's polymorphic properties against the attribute name used to identify your `polymorphic ids and types`:

```
/**
 * Note Model
 */
public function noteable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

Now you can simply call `->noteable` on the `(A/B/C)` models, and they all share 1 table without the need of another pivot table for each table.