# Can I have a constraint on count of distinct values in a column in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

Table: **Relatives**

- `emp_id`
- `dep_id`(composite primary key)

We have to restrict one employee to three dependents.

Comment: Why not create a trigger instead?

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522320/what-is-the-best-way-to-enforce-a-subset-relationship-with-integrity-constrain

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This cannot be done using a check constraint alone, but there is a way using a materialized view and a check constraint as I demonstrate [here on my blog](http://tonyandrews.blogspot.com/search/label/constraints).  For your example this would be:

```
create materialized view emp_dep_mv
build immediate
refresh complete on commit as
select emp_id, count(*) cnt
from relatives
group by emp_id;

alter table emp_dep_mv
add constraint emp_dep_mv_chk
check (cnt <= 3)
deferrable;
```

However, this approach might not be performant in a large, busy production database, in which case you could go for an approach that uses triggers and a check constraint, plus an extra column on the employees table:

```
alter table employees add num_relatives number(1,0) default 0 not null;

-- Populate for existing data
update employees
set num_relatives = (select count(*) from relatives r
                     where r.emp_id = e.emp_id)
where exists (select * from relatives r
              where r.emp_id = e.emp_id);

alter table employees add constraint emp_relatives_chk
check (num_relatives <= 3);

create trigger relatives_trg
after insert or update or delete on relatives
for each row
begin
   if inserting or updating then
      update employees
      set    num_relatives = num_relatives + 1
      where  emp_id = :new.emp_id;
   end if;
   if deleting or updating then
      update employees
      set    num_relatives = num_relatives - 1
      where  emp_id = :old.emp_id;
   end if;
end;
```

Comment: I am not satisfied... my requirements need a simple constraint in the first go (during table creation)... An inside-out approach... I think it is not possible at row-level, or is it?

Comment: You are correct: your requirements cannot be fulfilled.  It is impossible to create just a simple constraint to enforce this rule.

Comment: The revised version of onedaywhen's answer should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Add an new integer not null column `occurrence`, add a check constraint `occurrence BETWEEN 1 AND 3`, add a unique constraint on the compound of `emp_id` and `occurrence`, optionally add helper procs to maintain `occurrence` values.