# Check constrain with 2 tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables: `beds` and `room` and I want to make sure that on insert each room can have a maximum of 5 beds (i.e. the company owns 50 beds in total which can get swapped from room to room in various combinations but each room can only have 5 at the most).

The primary key in beds is a composite key of `room_id` and `bed_id` (`room_id` being the foreign key) but I'm not sure how to implement this as a constraint for the table?

TABLES BELOW

```
CREATE TABLE "ROOM"
   ("ROOM_NO" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "ROOM_NAME" VARCHAR2(45 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "ROOM_NO_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ROOM_NO")



CREATE TABLE "BED" 
   ("ROOM_NO" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "BED_NO" NUMBER(*,0), 
     CONSTRAINT "BED_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ROOM_NO", "BED_NO")
```

I'm new to sql and have not covered triggers and sequences please can you explain in simple terms how to do this?

Comment: I think you will need a trigger to manage this.

Comment: or have it controlled from the application over a global threshold

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8770552/can-i-have-a-constraint-on-count-of-distinct-values-in-a-column-in-sql, which references this blog post http://tonyandrews.blogspot.com/search/label/constraints

Comment: I agree with @GordonLinoff this can be solved with triggers. If you want help with trigger solution thought  you should provide some sample table structures, data   and more clearly describe expected behaviour.

Comment: @Plirkee A hotel has a store of 50 beds numbered from 1 to 50 but I want to ensure that a room can have any number of beds from the store. numbered start at 1 to a maximum of 5. So room 1 could have bed 1, bed, 2 then room 2 would have bed 1 bed 2 bed 3 bed 4 so there bed 1 in room 1 and bed 1 in room 2 should be different beds (I hope this makes sense.

Comment: @Plirkee A hotel has a store of 50 beds numbered from 1 to 50 but I want to ensure that a room can have any number of beds from the store, numbers start at 1 to a maximum of 5. So room 1 could have bed 1, bed, 2 then room 2 could have bed 1 bed 2 bed 3 bed 4 so bed 1 in room 1 and bed 1 in room 2 should be different beds (I hope this makes sense)

Comment: Now that I had a second look at it, it might be not that simple. as, if one would like to put a `trigger` on `bed` table - one would be facing `mutating trigger` problem (trigger trying to access data of a table that is being updated)...wonder what @GordonLinoff thinks about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok , based on your comment I'll modify the approach a bit

Here we go :

```
    CREATE TABLE "BED" 
   (
    "BED_NO" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "ROOM_NO" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "BED_ROOM_SN" NUMBER(*,0),   

     CONSTRAINT "BED_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("BED_NO"),
     CONSTRAINT rm_fk FOREIGN KEY ("ROOM_NO") REFERENCES "ROOM",
     CONSTRAINT chk_beds CHECK ("BED_ROOM_SN" IN (1,2,3,4,5)),
     CONSTRAINT constraint_name UNIQUE ("ROOM_NO", "BED_ROOM_SN")
    )
```

And I'll explain:

`BED` table contains:

- `BED_NO` (bed serial number, also a key in this    table ... in your
  case - numbers `1..50`)
- `ROOM_NO` - room number (a foreign key, referencing  `ROOM` table)
- `BED_ROOM_SN` - SN of the bed inside a room, that could only be from    `1` to `5`
- Also, a room can have only one first bed, one second bed etc - hence `unique`       (`Room_no,BED_ROOM_SN`)

Regarding normalization, here we have `one-to-many` relation (one `room` has many `beds`, however one `bed` goes only into one `room`), so that's why `room`'s key goes as `foreign key` to `bed` table.

Comment: That's the table structure I went with originally but the question specifically asks for bed and room to be in separate table after normalisation.

Comment: @user3185534 did you mention that in your question? cause I am using tables given in your question and just adding an extra constrain. I am not following ... what exactly do you mean 'bed and room to be separate after normalisation'?

Comment: thanks for the help..this seems so solve the problem.