# exclusive/disjoint inheritance in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I was wondering how to implement exclusive inheritance in SQlite. By doing simply

```
create table Class (id integer primary key);
create table Sub1(id integer primary key references Class(id));
create table Sub2(id integer primary key references Class(id));
```

I have simple inheritance which does not prevent a `Class` to be both `Sub1` and `Sub2`. I am looking for a way to enforce that a `Class` cannot be both (and optionnally, enforce it to be at least one of them).

In theory this could be possible with checks, e.g. for `Sub2`, something like

```
create table Sub2(id integer primary key references Class(id)
  check(not exists(select 1 from Sub1 where Sub1.id = id limit 1)));
```

but this has the drawback that it would require maintenance as subclasses are added, and also that it is not accepted by SQLite (`subqueries prohibited in CHECK constraints`). This does not work when the check is at the table level either.

EDIT

Found a similar question (and related answers) on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332602/maintaining-subclass-integrity-in-a-relational-database.).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maintaining subclass integrity in a relational database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332602/maintaining-subclass-integrity-in-a-relational-database)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use triggers (http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html).

For instance, you could implement your needs by creating a trigger for the table `Sub(n)` that, when a record is inserted in `Sub(n)`, checks that its primary key is not alread present in `Class`; if it is present than fails since this means that another record with the same primary key is already present in another `Sub(k)` table, otherwise it insert the (primary key of the) record in `Class`.

In this way, you can add tables corresponding to subclasses without modifying the code of the previous tables.

Comment: That indeed works nicely when the base class is empty, as my example misleadingly underlies. When it is not empty -- most common case I would assume -- the extra column technique proposed in the link I added provides a working solution.

Comment: Yes, this is true, but I would like also point you to another possibility: you can define a subclass, let's say `Sub(0)`, that contains only the elements of the base class, so that you have the previous solution. And I can imagine other possibilities, as well. What I want principally point out in my answer is that, given the limitations of SQLite checks, the only way to go is through triggers. And in my answer I was giving just an example of using them, but the right solution depends on the precise aspects of the problem!

Comment: I am not sure how your second solution would work out. If `Sub0` contains the elements of the base class, how would `Sub1` collect information from `Sub0` if they are exclusive? Or maybe are you saying all base class columns should be duplicated in the `Subn`s? I think that would defeat the purpose of this inheritance pattern.

Comment: You are correct, and I was wrong. But I was misleaded again by the fact that in the example case the Base table has only the key attribute :)